# Android DatePicker question

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a DatePicker and I have it set in my xml for my activity. I can read the year, month, and day from it, but here's the interesting thing, if user uses the arrow buttons above and below the the date fields, it works great, but if the user taps the number and enters a number via input method, and I have an OK button that reads the DatePicker with getYear(), getMonth(), and getDate(), the numbers aren't updated or something and I think I need to implement a listener of some sort, but I'm a bit stuck. Any suggestions?

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting an onDateChangedListener via the DatePicker's init() method, as shown below:

```
// member variables, initialize to today's date
int mYear = 2011;
int mMonth = 4;
int mDay = 30;

// following goes inside Activity's onCreate method
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.your_date_picker);
OnDateChangedListener listener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
    }
};
dp.init(mYear, mMonth, mDay, listener);
```

Comment: You're most welcome! Please "accept" to mark this question as answered if you feel that it has been fully.