# What is android "Date changed Listener" Event?

Tags: android, events, date, listener, onchange

Is there any event in android to trig when Date changed? 
I'm developing an widget and to display some task on widget. so i need to know what is date is it and whenever it changed.

Comment: setOnDateChangedListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this :

[Android - OnDateChangedListener - how do you set this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051153/android-ondatechangedlistener-how-do-you-set-this)

[Android DatePicker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839772/android-datepicker-question)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html

Comment: Those are for when the user has chosen a date in a date picker dialog. The question is for when the actual date (today) has changed. For example, now it's 23:59 of Sunday, and in 2 minutes it will be 0:01 of Monday.